# External Tools to Edit Questions and Answers

Tags: discussion, editing, howto

### Question:

What external tools are there to edit your own Questions and Answers
To minimize the number of edits submitted to the site, are there any plugins, practices, or other ways to minimize the number of edits required in complex answers?

---

When editing your own questions, and answers, it is often the case that some mistakes are not noticeable until the third re-read, or fourth ...

(I am quite guilty of unintentionally throwing comma splices everywhere--which I don't catch until the 8th edit, or two ...  And then there are the stylization edits ...)

Comment: why do you want to minimize the number of edits submitted to the site?

Comment: @JackDouglas  I think the user would like to minimize the number of edits required in their own responses. It is a Good Question-one which computer savvy folks seem to have an edge on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a suggestion. You can use a Markdown<sup>1</sup> editor (installed *locally* on your computer).

There are many options available for Windows<sup>2</sup>, Linux<sup>3</sup> or Mac<sup>4</sup>. On Windows, I have used [MarkdownPad 2](http://markdownpad.com/) and [Haroopad](http://pad.haroopress.com/). On Linux (Ubuntu), I have used [Remarkable](https://remarkableapp.github.io/).

Since the good answers will require much time, you could save your answer as a file with extension `.md` to your computer to continue in the following available time and improve your answer.

If you want to add images, upload them to [`http://imgur.com/`](http://imgur.com/), copy the generated link to use in your answer.

When the answer is complete, copy and paste the markdown code to the editor online on this site.

---

*Notes*

1. Such editors must support the 1.0 version of Markdown, although many editors offer other flavors of Markdown that are not compatible with this site. Simply do not use these features (tables, etc.).
2. See [*Markdown Preview Application for Windows*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204647/markdown-preview-application-for-windows)
3. See [*Markdown Viewer*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4140/markdown-viewer)
4. See [*Markdown editor for OSX that includes a preview, ideally in real time?*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25/markdown-editor-for-osx-that-includes-a-preview-ideally-in-real-time).

Comment: Hi! Is there anything that will work with an iPad 2 running iOS 8.1.1? Safari's my default browser but I also use Chrome. I learn so much from your great site, but haven't contributed in large part because of the difficulty of writing long questions, answers and edits! I usually cut/paste into Notes but it's exhausting, and doesn't support Markdown. Thank you in advance and God bless you!

Comment: @Sue Hi! Humm ... you can use an application for iPad instead of the browser, e.g. [Byword](https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/id482063361) or [Editorial](https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/id673907758). For what it is worth! :)

Comment: It's worth a tremendous amount, thanks! I should have thought to look for an app. I'm in NJ this weekend where my husband's attending a bible conference, so I won't have a lot of time, but will look at those. Thank you for understanding that not everyone can have a desktop or laptop :)